# Finding A Particular generation function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am trying to find a generating function for the sequence
$$a_n = \binom{n+3}{3}.$$

I can see that $\binom{n+3}{3} = \frac{(n+3)!}{(n)!3!} = \frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{
6}.$ This gives me a very direct template to work with for my generating
function. I see that by the geometric series,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i+3} = \frac{x^3}{1-x},$$
which if we differentiate with respect to $x$,
$$\implies \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i+3)x^{i+2} = \frac{(3-2x)x^2}{(1-x)^2}.$$

I am starting to realize that if I continue on this path, I will have
significantly more difficult derivatives to consider as I approach dealing
with the triple derivative of $\frac{x^2}{1-x}$. Is there potentially a
simpler way to handle this problem in relation to the geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go this route:

Start with
$$
A(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)x^n
$$
Note that this looks an awful lot like
$$
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)x^n\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[C_1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+3)x^{n+1}\right]\\
&=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[C_2+C_1x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+3)x^{n+2}\right]\\
&=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left[C_3+C_2x+\frac{C_1x^2}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+3}\right],
\end{align*}
$$
for any choice of the constants $C_1,C_2,C_3$. We could take, for instance, $C_1=2$ and $C_2=C_3=1$, and re-index the sum, to say that
$$
A(x)=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right]=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right].
$$
But, of course, we can take derivatives of this easily enough:
$$
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right]=\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you can solve a problem by generalization.

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, consider following generalization of your OGF:
$$g_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$$

The OGF of these OGFs equals to:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k(x)t^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n t^k = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}x^{m-k}t^k
= \sum_{m=0}^\infty (x+t)^m\\
= \frac{1}{1-(x+t)}
= \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-\frac{t}{1-x})}
= \frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{t}{1-x}\right)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$
Compare coefficient of $t^k$ on both sides, we get

$$g_k(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

In particular, the OGF you seek is $\displaystyle\;g_3(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe, formally we have
\begin{align}
\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=3}n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3} = \sum_{n=0}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)x^n.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = \sum_{n=0}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n.
\end{align}